# UWP build menu with checkboxes to select few options

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

If I want to create a menu where user can select several options.
In Silverlight I use free menu control which can have checkboxes.

**Can I have a MenuFlyoutItem with a checkbox?** *And that it doesn't close menu if I click on it - it should flip the checkbox but stay open.*

example

```
Export to: <- menu item
   Excel   <- sub-menu items with checkboxes...
   CSV
   Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add the the `CheckBox` in the `Template` of the `MenuFlyoutItem`, then we can use the `TemplateBinding` to bind the `Text` property of the `MenuFlyoutItem` to the `Content` property of the `CheckBox`.

By default, when we click the `CheckBox` in the `MenuFlyout`, the `MenuFlyout` will still open.

For example:

```
<Button Content="Open MenuFlyout">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 1">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                        <StackPanel Margin="12,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox Content="{TemplateBinding Text}"></CheckBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 2">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                        <StackPanel Margin="12,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox Content="{TemplateBinding Text}"></CheckBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

Comment: then I will have to bind checkboxes `IsChecked` to some data property - to get the values.. right?

Comment: If you want get the `IsChecked`, we can use the `Checked` and `Unchecked` event to get that. You can also bind it to the some data property.

Answer (score 2):

Just substitute ToggleMenuFlyoutItem for MenuFlyoutItem, much simpler. You will be able to use checked and unchecked.

```
<ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Name="filter_high_power" Text="Filter High Power" Click="Filter_high_power_Checked" />
```